# How to check for errors in nanosleep loop

Tags: c, unix, sleep

I have a nanosleep function in while loop. This is an example I found in book "Linux System Programming: Talking Directly to the Kernel and C Library"

```
    while(nanosleep(a, b) && errno==EINTR){
        struct timespec *tmp =a;
        a=b;
        b=tmp;
    }
```

Works perfect but I am not sure how can I check for other errors than EINTR so that I can print error on the screen and exit the program. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply store the return value in the loop condition:

```
int ret;
while((ret = nanosleep(a, b)) && errno==EINTR){
    struct timespec *tmp =a;
    a=b;
    b=tmp;
}
if (ret) {
    perror("nanosleep");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: yup — copy-paste blindness

Comment: @xwhyz: No, you need more parentheses.